# Command \algorithmic already defined

Tags: beamer, packages

Here is the list of packages I load for my presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}%
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{environ}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows,shapes.multipart}
```

There are 4 packages (as follows) that I use for my `article`, but if I add them to the list, 
it gives me an error `Command \algorithmic already defined`. I guess some packages are not compatible with the one above:

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor,lipsum}
```

Without loading the 4 packages, one problem is that a formula like `abc_\textbf{index}` which works in my article does not work anymore, so I need to change it to `abc_{\textbf{index}}`. And I have a lot of formulae having that...

So could anyone tell me which package is relevant to that? and how to add it to the list for my presentation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `algpseudocode` defines an `algorithmic` environment (and therefore not compatible). That's what `algcompatible` is for. See the [`algorithmicx` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf#page=3). However, also as mentioned in the documentation, this is "used only in old documents."

Comment: Thanks for your reply... but the other 3 packages still can not be used, and the formula of `abc_\textbf{index}` is still not accepted.

Comment: Are all the packages you load really necessary? `multicol`: `beamer` provides a `columns` environment; `float`, `longtable`: do you have any of these in your presentation? Regarding `abc_\textbf{index}` vs. `abc_{\textbf{index}}`: Using the `article` documentclass rather than `beamer` in a minimal example works for both, but on the latter works in `beamer`. Or does the loading of the mentioned 4 packages solve this problem in `beamer`?

Comment: @Werner: would you make an answer out of your comments?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11):

`algpseudocode` (as part of the [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)) defines an `algorithmic` environment, and is therefore not compatible. That is, [`algorithmicx.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.sty) defines the `algorithmic` environment using

```
\newenvironment{algorithmic}[1][0]%
  {...}
```

Specifying the package option

```
\usepackage[algcompatible]{algpseudocode}
```

only allows for compatibility with the former [`algorithmic` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmic) **notation**. That is, commands like `\REQUIRE`, `\ENSURE`, `\STATE` and `\COMMENT` are directed to imply `\item[\algorithmicrequire]`, `\item[\algorithmicensure]`, `\State` and `\Comment` under `algorithmicx`. Regardless, you are not able to use *both* `algorithmic` and `algorithmicx` in your document preamble.

The [`beamer` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) does not enjoy `abc_\textbf{index}`, while the `article` document class doesn't complain. I'm guessing there might be something internally done by `beamer` that modifies the regular usage. If this is problematic, I'm sure you could use something like [`sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) to parse your existing `.tex` document and replace all occurrences of `<stuff>_<sub-stuff>` with `<stuff>_{<sub-stuff>}`. Regardless, if this is a restriction in `beamer`, it may be useful to embrace it, both literally and figuratively.