# "Command \algorithmic already defined" when attempting to compile in MiKTeX/TeXworks

Tags: packages, miktex, compilation-error, texworks, preamble

I have two questions about the error message described by the subject line.

My first question is why does Overleaf not have this error? And my second question is how do I solve this problem?

I was using Overleaf, but I wanted to change to software installed locally so I don't need internet or have to worry about Overleaf's compilation time limit.

I cannot provide all code here to recreate the problem, as it requires a bunch of other files to be recreated. Instead, here is a link to the template I used, which contains all of the files:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/homework-solutions/xykkzgnbzmxp

I tried to include the code from packages.tex, but StackExchange couldn't detect the newlines and it all appeared as one line. But it is inside the Overleaf template.

I downloaded the project folder from my Overleaf account to my computer and tried compiling it in MiKTex/TeXworks (I installed MiKTex, but the software is called TeXworks after being installed). It gives the following error message:

[image: Error Message]

I have already done research into finding a solution. The following threads have the same error:

[Command \algorithmic already defined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26921/command-algorithmic-already-defined)
For this one, the proposed solution is not apparent to me. I read it a few times, and could not find how they solved the problem/where the solution is described here.

[algorithm2e Command \algorithm already defined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131646/algorithm2e-command-algorithm-already-defined)
For this one, the source of the problem is different, and I cannot figure out how to use their solution in my case. They are using a package called algorithm2e, but I am not using this package. I took a shot in the dark and tried changing "\usepackage{algpseudocode}" to "\usepackage[algo2e]{algpseudocode}", but nothing changed.

Can anyone help me? I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: if you add `\listfiles` and compare the list at the end of the log you will see which package versions are different

Comment: you are using algorithm and algorithmx which is presumably the problem

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so that people can test your code. Also, avoid screenshots and provide the log as text. Finally, Overleaf handles errors badly so make sure that it's not just ignoring errors.